# Fabric JS, How to adjust canvas so that when object is added on zoom its coordinates are correct?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Currently i am using the following method to clone objects on the drag of a handle. This works fine but when i add zoom or pan into the equation they are completely off target from original position. see fiddle for original http://jsfiddle.net/matthew_hardern/y0ebkvbn/14/

can't seem to get zoom working on fiddle so not sure i can demonstrate the issue, but zooming code is:

```
this.canvas.on('mouse:wheel', (opt) => {
  var e = opt.e;
  var newZoom = this.canvas.getZoom() + e.deltaY / 300;
  //get center
  var center = this.canvas.getCenter();
  if (newZoom >= this.minZoom && newZoom <= this.maxZoom) {
    //set zoom
    this.zoomLevel = newZoom;
    //set zoom on center
    this.canvas.zoomToPoint({x: center.left, y: center.top}, this.zoomLevel);

    var objects = this.canvas.getObjects();

    for (var i in objects) {
      objects[i].setCoords();
    }

    this.canvas.renderAll();
    this.canvas.calcOffset();
  }

  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

At the moment i am looking for a way to update the canvas so that when it clones zoomed in it clones in same position as original when zoomed in or panned.

Thanks any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: so basically you are facing an issue with zooming your canvas. The objects are getting displaced, correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: nope thats correct they get displaced when zoomed or panned

Comment: just as a pointer this only happens when adding / cloning

Comment: Actually when the canvas is zoomed all the objects are also scaled accordingly. I dont see them being displaced. Or i m not getting the issue completely. Please elaborate. Here is a fiddle have a look with zoom on mouse wheel. when you select the object its logs its position to console. I see proper result no deviation even if then canvas is zoomed. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0ebkvbn/19/)